# How to get PhpStorm to recognize Laravel facades?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

When using Laravel Framework (5.6), PhpStorm does not recognize methods when accessed via facades like this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

So it's always complaining that: "Method 'find' not found in User"

[image: error message]

I've got the Laravel Plugin & the Barry IDE Helper.  What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the root of your project in terminal:

```
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

Reference: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdoc-generation-for-laravel-facades

Comment: oh, perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: add before running 2nd command: `composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

Answer (score 1):

If you need auto-completion for facades in your custom package, then you might want to use the `@mixin` PhpDocBlock attribute to link the class that you are accessing through the facade to your facade.

- [Auto-Completion for Laravel Facades](https://thomasventurini.com/articles/auto-completion-for-laravel-facades/)

Comment: Note, that your proposed way will throw inspections for `Dynamic method called statically`